# (Python, BeautifulSoup) Create or modify a list of anchor text without anchor tags

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to build a script that extracts some text from a website and pastes it in a Google spreadsheet.

The text are titles that are wrapped in a tags on the website. I'm using BeautifulSoup (and have pygspread imported too) to extract the titles likes this:

```
target_url = 'WEBSITE URL'
r = requests.get(target_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

seminarTitles = soup.findAll("a",{"class":"eventCardHead--title"})

for title in seminarTitles:
   print(title.text)
```

This extracts the titles between the a tags and prints them. However instead of printing I want to paste the list items in a Google sheet so I need the list to be formated correctly with only the titles like ["Title1","Title2",...]. but with this code the list still contains all the a tags. But how do I can I use the (title.text) operation to format the list or how can I create a correctly formatted list right away?

Comment: Can you provide the link of website, that you want to retrieve titles from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
target_url = 'WEBSITE URL'
r = requests.get(target_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

seminarTitles = soup.findAll("a",{"class":"eventCardHead--title"})
Titles = []
for title in seminarTitles:
   Titles.append(title.text)

print(Titles)
```

Output:

```
["Title1","Title2",...]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I saw looking for.

I found an alternative solution in the meantime. Instead of filling in the list afterwards with append(title.text) I defined the lists like this and it gave the same result:

seminarsTitleList = [seminarTitle.get_text() for seminarTitle in seminarTitles]